# jQuery Datatables - Can't get input value from hidden pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, datatables

I have this table in my HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Actual weight</th>
            <th>New weight</th>
        </tr>      
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td><input data-id="{{ object.id }}" type="number" name="input_new_weight" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td><input data-id="{{ object.id }}" type="number" name="input_new_weight" /></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- multiply by 10 the number of trs -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I have this code in my javascript to get the input values:

```
var new_weights = []
$("input[name='input_new_weight']").each(function(index, element){

    if( $(this).val() != "" ){
        var object_new_weight ={
            id: $(this).data('id'),
            new_weight: $(this).val()
        }
        new_weights.push(object_new_weight);
    }

});
console.log(new_weights);
```

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin to generate the tables and have the possibili ty to filter, paginate, ordenate and etc.

In some tables I have more than 10 entries, so the paginations works here. In the example above, it will be 2 pages: 1 and 2.

When my javascript code is executed, it does only gets the inputs values from the visible table page. The inputs from the hidden pages are not get!

Let's suppose that in page 1 I put the new weight values as 35, 75 and 80 and in the page 2 I put 40, 54, 97. When my javascript code runs, it does just get the values from the visible page.

Please, can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I'm using jQuery DataTables. The pagination it's dinamically done in the same page, without redirection.

Comment: I've not used JQuery Datatables but what do you see in the DOM? using developers tools (F12) you should see how many rows of data is there but hidden. I suspect that the rows are drawn page by page based on data in the memory. So the DOM only has the input fields of the current page. A suggestion would be to read the data on page change and store it. Then process the values from storage and not the DOM itself.

Comment: Use the Datatables API to access the data. For filtering and pagination only the associated rows are rendered...all else is stored in caches within the plugin

Comment: Understood... So I must use the API with table.cell().cache() to try to get the input values?

Answer (score 0):

It's really straightforward you know datatable generates table on the fly so when you are on page 1, inputs corresponding to page 2 (40, 54, 97) **aren't there at all** on the page.

So I am guessing you have put your this code out in the global

```
$("input[name='input_new_weight']").each(function(index, element){
    //stuff
});
```

This runs only one time; on initial loading of your page when inputs from only page 1 are there, what you rather need is to be able to run your code every-time datatable re-renders.There's a hook that you may use [`page.dt`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page)

Put this after the code where you initialize datatable

```
$('#yourtable').on('page.dt', function(){

    $("input[name='input_new_weight']").each(function(index, element){
        //stuff
    });

});
```